# GetEntity vs ReadEntity in Response (Javax.ws.rs)

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am writing a client to consume a RestService and I have to read an entity out of the response and I am totally confused which method out of the two (`getEntity` vs `readEntity`) should be used.

I have to retrieve the entity whenever I get a WebApplicationException.

So, my code more or less looks like.

```
catch(WebApplicationException ex) {
// Do something with ex.getResponse
}
```

From, whatever I have tested,

```
ex.getResponse().hasEntity() ---> true

ex.getResponse().getEntity() == null ---> true
```

I don't know how it is working but if the first is true then how second statement could be true.

Surprisingly, readEntity worked fine for me and I was able to read the 
 entity out from the response.

But, after reading the entity through readEntity,

this call gives false.

```
 ex.getResponse().getEntity() == null --> false
```

Can someone help me understand what is really happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behaviour is documented in the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-):

> `public abstract <T> T readEntity(Class<T> entityType)`
>
> Read the message entity input stream as an instance of specified Java type using a MessageBodyReader that supports mapping the message entity stream onto the requested type.
>
> [...]
>
> A message instance returned from this method **will be cached for subsequent retrievals via getEntity()**.

The first call to `ex.getResponse().getEntity()` is null, because the Entity hasn't been read yet. After calling `readEntity()`, the parsed entity will be returned as parsed by `getEntity()`.

Answer (score 23):

The `Response` class has two uses: server side and client side. On the server side, it's called the *outbound* response. On the client, it's *inbound* response.

**Outbound**

```
@GET
public Response get() {
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    return Response.ok(model).build();
}
```

**Inbound**

```
Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(url).request().get();
```

The `getEntity()` method is meant to be used on the server side because you want to *get* the entity *object*. There's not much use for it for us, but Jersey will use it to get the entity object to serialize it before it sends it out.

The `readEntity()` method is to be used on the client side because you are trying to *read* the entity stream. If you try to call this on the server side, you will get an error saying that you can't read the stream on an outbound response.

As far as the behavior you're experiencing, I can't really explain why they implemented like this.

Comment: But how I can generate the object of Response during unit testing, read entity does not work there (says entity is not backed by a stream). While getEntity works fine.

Comment: I struggled with this problem for probably half a day.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @TastyWheat No problem. It's _is_ a bit confusing using the same class for two different general use cases. But still, my answer did not directly answer the asked question. The accepted on _does_ have the correct answer. I just added a little more information about how the class works in general.