# In integration test case in one scenario i want to add data inside of response.ok(returns java objects) to one obj..how can we do that

Tags: java, rest, integration-testing, webservice-client

used this String output = response.readEntity(String.class); But getting IllegalStateException how to resolve this..getEntity(); is also throwing exception

Comment: Would be great if you provided [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48781860/2587435) might give you some information that might help.

Comment: While debugging from the line getEntity() & readEntity() i used both at different times throws exception i couldnot understand how can i get info from response.ok() other than status