# JAX-RS Response.getEntity() always null

Tags: jax-rs

I need help with Arquillian test.

Add code example of situation.
This code is working ok in real environment. Only in test case made with arquillian the result is not expected

The code:

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerResourceImpl implements CustomerResource{
    @Override
    public Response findOne(String id) {
        String res = "Un cliente";
        return Response.ok(res).build();
    }
}


@Path("customer")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface CustomerResource {
    
    @GET
    @Path("/findOne")
    public javax.ws.rs.core.Response findOne(@QueryParam("id") String id);

}
```

And this test case

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class CustomerResourceTest {

    @Deployment (testable = false)
    public static Archive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap
                ..... (mas)
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }
    
    @ArquillianResource
    private URL deploymentURL;

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void findOne(@ArquillianResteasyResource CustomerResource resource) throws Exception {
        final Response response = resource.findOne("1");
        System.out.println(response.getEntity()); // IS NULL ??
        System.out.println(response.getStatus()); // 200 OK
        assertNotNull(response);
    }       
}
```

The problem is that response.getEntity() is always NULL . Why? The status response OK = 200 , it is OK. This service run ok in jboss 7.2 with Java 8.

Thanks!

Comment: I find the solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781860/getentity-vs-readentity-in-response-javax-ws-rs Slds!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `@Deployment (testable = false)`

[@Deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/api/latest/org/jboss/arquillian/container/test/api/Deployment.html) says:

> testable = Defines if this deployment should be wrapped up based on the protocol so the testcase can be executed incontainer.

So false means it **will not** be deployed in the container, and therefore will be null when your tests run inside the container.

I recommend using `@Deployment` with not parameters passed in rather than setting `testable = true`

I just solved this today after a days of fiddling. I think I pasted the `@Deployment (testable = false)` code from examples on the internet that I didn't understand hoping to get something working.

Comment: Bae, thank you for you response but is not work.
I find solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781860/getentity-vs-readentity-in-response-javax-ws-rs

Comment: Ahh, can you write your own answer then?
I'll update the title with the correct question